# How should a void function be tested in googletest

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-c++, googletest

This void function sets the value of the parameter (which is of a type enum) when called and given the enumerator name. The variable, which where this function stores the value being set, is private static. I am looking for a way that I could access this variable somehow or be able to get a string from another void function.

Example:

```
class A
{
public:
    enum Temperature
    {
        Low,
        Medium,
        High
    };

    static void Add(Temperature temperature);

private:
    static Temperature  tempval;

};

int main()
{
   int x = A::Add(A::Low);

   A::Add(A::Low);

   EXPECT_EQ(x, A::Add);
}
```

Comment: You should be posting some code sample for seeing really what you mean. Anyway, you should design your code to be testable : if some function is to be tested, it does something on some data. So this data should be either returned as a return value or as an output parameter.

Comment: I added an example of what I would like to accomplish.

Comment: You need to test the side effects of the function. In this case, did `tempval` change to the appropriate value? If you have no method exposed to the test rig that can display `tempval`, you have to find some other behaviour you can monitor to show the effect of the function call. If there are no visible effects, you need to stop and ask yourself, "Do I really need this function at all?"

Comment: Does it even compile? How come you create `x` from method that returns void? I'd go ahead and add `Get` method to test what is `tempval` after `Add` was called.